# Get 5 values from user in single veriable without array or any loop and find the max and min value

Tags: c#

Write a program which get five values in a single variable without using array or any loop and find the maximum and minimum number using if else condition.

Comment: You forgot to tell what we get to do your work. Anyway, it's off-topic here. Maybe you want to try something yourself, show it, describe what you want to do and what does happen instead. Then we can try to help.

Comment: And unless you want your phone-number to be used for spamming (receive or be used as a fake source) then don't post it in public forums.

Comment: Some programmer dude this is my assignment please give me answer

Comment: @Farhan.  This is homework.  Part of learning to program is (ahem) actually writing code.  Even if the code is not correct.  Post what you've got so far and you will get an answer.  You're not going to learn anything if someone just gives you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your puzzle can be solved by bit shift manipulation to store and extract multiple variables within another. Below is a demonstration -- [see this blog post for an in depth explanation on what's going on](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2007/12/28/network-compression-bitfields/). If you are interested in additional bit-wise manipulation [you can find more C++ examples here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) (easily convertible into C#).

```
enum Species
{
    Camel,
    Cat,
    Caterpillar,
    Cheetah,
    Chimpanzee,
    Cobra,
    Cormorant,
    Cougar,
    Coyote,
    Crab,
    Crocodile,
}

void AddToBitfield(ref int bitfield, int bitCount, int value)
{
    bitfield <<= bitCount;
    bitfield |= value;
}

int ReadFromBitfield(ref int bitfield, int bitCount)
{
    int value = bitfield & ((1 << bitCount) - 1);
    bitfield >>= bitCount;
    return value;
}


[Test]
public void BitwisePlayTest()
{
    bool isAlive      = true;
    bool isFiring     = false;
    bool isMale       = true;
    bool isFullHealth = false;
    Species species = Species.Chimpanzee;

    int bitfield = 0;

    AddToBitfield(ref bitfield, 1, isAlive ? 1 : 0);
    AddToBitfield(ref bitfield, 1, isFiring ? 1 : 0);
    AddToBitfield(ref bitfield, 1, isMale ? 1 : 0);
    AddToBitfield(ref bitfield, 1, isFullHealth ? 1 : 0);
    AddToBitfield(ref bitfield, 4, (int)species);

    species = (Species)ReadFromBitfield(ref bitfield, 4);
    isFullHealth = ReadFromBitfield(ref bitfield, 1) != 0;
    isMale = ReadFromBitfield(ref bitfield, 1) != 0;
    isFiring = ReadFromBitfield(ref bitfield, 1) != 0;
    isAlive = ReadFromBitfield(ref bitfield, 1) != 0;

    Assert.AreEqual(Species.Chimpanzee, species);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, isAlive);
    Assert.AreEqual(false, isFiring);
    Assert.AreEqual(false, isFullHealth);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, isMale);
}
```